# IChing one click at a time

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I'm learning swift and doing an iching app for practice. I've got the six lines 'randomly generating', but the whole hexagram appears on a single press of my button. I need the lines to appear 'one by one' therefore requiring the user to press the same button six times to create a hexagram. I've got no clear idea of how to do this.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please provide some code that you've tried.

Comment: Haven't tried anything yet to achive this end because I'm not sure how to go about it.

Comment: What code do you use to display the hexagram now?

Comment: Hi, Way too long to post in here. This is one line of hexagram.                                                                   
        ' '@'IBOutlet weak var lineOne: UIImageView!
    
        let linesArray:[String] = ["Y1","Y4","Y2","Y1","Y3","Y4"]  
        self.lineOne.image = UIImage(named: "line1")
       
    '@'IBAction func ThrowCoin(sender: UIImage) {
        
        var firstRandomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(6))
       
            var lineOneString:String = self.linesArray[firstRandomNumber]
         
        self.lineOne.image = UIImage(named: lineOneString) '